# Google Sheet Script - remove row with specific data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a code that removes rows from the spreadsheet that contain specific words. 
How can I apply it not only to one column and search for only one word but to check several columns and several words?

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
    var row = values[i]; 
    if (row[21].indexOf('Wohnmobil') > -1) { 
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted); rowsDeleted++; 
    } 
  } 
};
```

With this code it looks through column V and removes rows with word "Wohnmobil".

How to make it check columns R and V for example and remove rows that contain words like "Wohnmobil", "WG", "Trailer", "Caravan"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 
  var arrayOfWords = ['Wohnmobil', ....] //this is your array of words to search

  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
    var row = values[i]; 
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfWords.length; j++) {    //loop thru your word list
      if (row.indexOf(arrayOfWords[j]) > -1) {         // search every column 
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1);     //since i loop runs from bottom row, you don't need to account for row number changes 
        rowsDeleted++;   
        break; //go out of j loop since a word has already been found and the row deleted        
      }
    } 
  } 
};
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help! Runs as I need it. Only I still specified the column I need to check for words as other columns may have those words too and I do not remove them if they are not in particular columns.

Comment: also, if I would like to define a specific range I want to apply the script for, for example V100:R700, where should I put it?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean to delete row only inside V100:R700, and leave out rows outside the range (meaning whatever outside the range but in the same row number won't be deleted)?

Comment: so that it wouldn't delete previous rows that I already have, meaning, check and delete only rows from row 100 for example and below but whatever is in rows 1-99 - those should not be checked by script.